# Different algorithms in MATLAB for multiplication of matrices

Tags: matrices, matlab

If $A\in \Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a lower triangular matrix  with $m<n$ and $B\in \Bbb{R}^{n\times p}$, how can I code this multiplication in a way that the null columns of $A$ will not be accessed? Can it be made by the modification (if i <= k) of one of these codes?

```
C = zeros(m,n)
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        s = 0
        for k=1:p
            s=s+A(i,k)*B(k,j)
        end
        C(i,j) = s
    end
end
```

```
C = zeros(m,n)
for j=1:n
         aux = zeros(m,1)
         for k=1:p
                for i=1:m
                        aux(i) = aux(i)+A(i,k)*B(k,j)
                end
        end
        C(:,j) = aux
end
```

```
C = zeros(m,n)
for k=1:p
    for i=1:m
        aux = zeros(1,n)
        for j=1:n
            aux(j) = aux(j)+A(i,k)*B(k,j)
        end
        C(i,:)=C(i,:)+aux
    end
end
```

Comment: This question is about coding, not math, and hence should be migrated.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ is lower triangular, if $i < k$, then $A_{ik}=0$. Hence we do not need to care about these terms and we only need to add up terms when $k \le i$.

$$C_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}B_{kj}=\sum_{k=\color{red}1}^{\color{red}i} A_{ik}B_{kj}$$

Also, note the following $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, $j$ should take values up to $p$.

The size of $C$ should be $m \times p$.

Comment: But by the condition "in a way that the null columns of A will not be accessed", which one of the three codes should I pick to do the modification?

Comment: I interpret your question as in avoid accesing those zero entries that are there due to definitions of lower triangular matrix. You can work on any of the code. While my formula is most natural for the first formulation, try to work on different order of for loop as well.